# In mongoose.js, can we search for a model with several search parameters?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jsobject, mongoose-models

Im using the module mongoose.js for my mongodb database.
My data base looks like this:

```
{
  thing1: "thing1",
  thing2: "thing2"
}
```

And I want to search a model with several parameters (thing1 and thing2).
I tried this:

```
myModel.findOne({ thing1: "thing1", thing2: "thing2" });
```

But it returned undefined.
So i searched on the mongoosejs docs, and then i tried this:

```
myModel.find({ thing1: "thing1", thing2: "thing2" });
```

But it returned an empty array.

What should i do?

Comment: Your logic is working fine: https://mongoplayground.net/p/_HL-85RAWms

Comment: I see, i'll search if there is another reason

Comment: i found the problem, it was just that i didn't declared the "thing2" when i created the new model ^^'

Answer (score 0):

I didn't declared the "thing2" in my model